# How to access two different database servers with Yesod/Persistent?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I'm building a website using Yesod and Persistent (I'm using the basic yesod  mysql scaffolding).
I need to access a different database that the main one, but `runDB` uses
the default connection parameter and connection. Is there a simple way to use Persistent with two different connection parameters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the scaffolded code, it should be easy to define another `rundDB` accessing another pool created with different connection parameters. This implies to also modify the `Settings` to read and stote the extra connection info.
However, one of the main issue is, one needs to remember which connection (or wich `runDB`) to use depending on the data type to load.  Another solution is to use federated tables.
MySql (or MariaDB) allows to create a proxy table connected to a remote database. Even though it needs a some setup, this as the advantage to be safe and easier to use on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

The function that creates a connection (like `runSqlite`) is in the `IO` monad. That means that you can call it in a `Handler` function in your Yesod application with `liftIO`. You can also immediately run queries on the database, so that's pretty neat.